# Custom Sort Specific Cell Values to Bottom of Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a shared workbook that multiple users updated constantly throughout the day.  The workbook is used as a live schedule of active repair jobs in through out my company's multiple repair facilities.  When a job is marked "done" it needs to be sorted to the bottom of the list so that only the active data can be viewed and is not cluttered by jobs that are "done".  The problem is that "done" starts with "d", which is earlier in the alphabet than the technician names that perform the work.

I've Sorting descending will not work as there are blanks and listed items that fall alphabetically on both sides of "done".

I've tried putting a "z" in front of the "done" and while that actually works, I'm trying to keep this as clean as possible.  I'd prefer to not do that.  I've also thought about adding an extra column that validates to the listed items, but there are 2 caveats to that.  1 - I'm actually trying to learn VBA and 2 - I'd like to keep the size of the file as small as possible.

When I job is marked "done", I need it to sort (as a worksheet change event) to the bottom.  How do I do this?

Below is an example of what I've started with.  Also, here's an example of the data that I'm working with.  The list below all appears in the same column.  This is critical to the way the workbook functions because "done" indicates that a technician is no longer working on the project and thus it is "done".  For anonymity, I've kept the names fiction, but the principle is the same.  The names, alphabetically, sort on both sides of "done". I need to sort alphabetically, but keep the "done" at the end of the list.

John Smith

Alex Smith

Brandon Smith

Nathan Smith

Done

```
With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3"), Order:=xlAscending '<-- I don't want to sort assending!!
     .SetRange Range("A3:S" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Sort Descending?

Comment: Use "zDone" text instead?

Comment: If I sort "descending" then the items that come alphabetically before "done" show up at the bottom.  I just need the "done" items at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Van Ng, I thought about doing that, but I'm trying to keep from anything showing up that will confuse the ones reading it.  The ones that will be reading this, will likely be confused about the "z".

Just to be clear, this is the only solution that I've found that actually works thus far.

Comment: I would suggest adding a column to show the status of the job, rather than using one column for more than one purpose (i.e. Name and Status), with the Status you use a data validation and will allow setting values to tell the different stages of the job (i..e Active, On Hold, Done, etc), while keeping the name of the employee who performed the job.

Answer (score 0):

If the raw underlying cell value is not important then there are a few ways that you can show the user *done* in a cell while the actual value of the cell is *zdone*. Conditional formatting is the first that comes to mind.

Alternately, a temporary 'helper' column can be inserted, populated, used as the primary key for a sort and then removed before control is passed back to the user.

An array of the data could be collected then custom sorted in memory according to any conditions that you code for before returning the sorted data back to the worksheet.

BTW, it is unclear on how sorting on *zdone* works as expected if there are blank cells involved. Blank cells should be pushed below *zdone* in an ascending sort so your *zdone* rows are not going to be at the bottom of the list.

Here is an array based solution that allows you to create any custom sorting algorithm that you can imagine.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CustomDoneArraySort()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, arr As Variant, tmp As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet4")

        'collect data from worksheet excluding header
        arr = .Range(.Cells(4, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Value

        'expand array to allow a 'helper column' in the second rank
        ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1), _
                           LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) + 1)

        'populate helper column
        'this can be as complicated as you want but it
        'will ultimately determine the finished sort order
        'this version will create a column where blanks are 'zz'
        'and 'done' is 'zzz' and other text is unchanged
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

            Select Case arr(i, 2)
              Case "done", "Done", "DONE"
                arr(i, UBound(arr, 2)) = "zzz"
              Case vbNullString
                arr(i, UBound(arr, 2)) = "zz"
              Case Else
                arr(i, UBound(arr, 2)) = arr(i, 2)
            End Select

        Next i

        'create a temporary array to use for shifting values
        ReDim tmp(LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2))

        'sort on the 'helper column'
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) - 1
            For j = i To UBound(arr, 1)
                'xlAscending sort
                If arr(i, UBound(arr, 2)) > arr(j, UBound(arr, 2)) Then
                    'store the values from the sorting shift target in tmp
                    For k = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
                        tmp(k) = arr(j, k)
                    Next k
                    'transfer the values from the sorting shift source to the sorting shift target
                    For k = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
                        arr(j, k) = arr(i, k)
                    Next k
                    'put the tmp values in the sorting shift source
                    For k = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
                        arr(i, k) = tmp(k)
                    Next k
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        'remove the array's 'helper column' in the second rank
        ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1), _
                           LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) - 1)

        'return sorted array to worksheet
        .Cells(4, "A").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr

    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I know the "helper" column would work.  i don't think it would have to be removed, but rather hidden to keep people from playing with it.  Can you explain how the array situation would work though?  

I've updated the data that I'm using above.

Comment: Now that I think about it, can you explain how you'd do this with conditional formatting and with an array via VBA?

Comment: For conditional formatting, use *zzz* instead of *done* in the cell. Create a CFR based on `=$B3="zzz"` and apply a custom number format of `\do\n\e;\do\n\e;\do\n\e;\do\n\e`. I'll work up an array solution using 3 columns of data based on your sample data of names/done in column B and post it above.

Comment: +1 for the conditional formatting, very clever indeed. Suggest to include those details in your answer, perhaps with the explanation of the custom number format.

Comment: @EEM - I'd rather not. My final edit is the best (IMHO) that I can offer. Alternates can be read from comments.